# Only detect nfc on a certain position of the code

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nfc

I have a problem. I am creating an app where you can buy stuff like Cola, Fanta, Water or whatever. So when you have chosen what you want to buy, you can press the button checkout. Then a Popup appears (as seen in the picture) where the user ist forced to hold a NFC Tag close to the device to acomplish the order. The NFC Detector should only be activated as long as you see the Popup. So when you are chosing what you want to get you dont accidentally hold the tag at the device and it does something.

Can you guys help me with that? Thank you very much!

[image]

```
package com.nfc.netvision;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.util.NumberUtils;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import static android.widget.Toast.*;

public class OrderActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OrderAdapter.TotalListener {

    private OrderAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<ModelOrder> orderArrayList;
    private TextView textView_order_price, textView_order_count;
    private Dialog epicDialog;
    private Button btnCheckout, btnAbort;


    // Nfc
    NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    IntentFilter writeTagFilters[];
    boolean writeMode;
    Tag myTag;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_order_scroll);
        textView_order_price = findViewById(R.id.textView_order_price);
        textView_order_count = findViewById(R.id.textView_order_count);
        btnCheckout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCheckout);


        orderArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        orderArrayList.add(new ModelOrder(R.drawable.coke, "Coka Cola", "Eine Cola hält dich wach und schmeckt dazu.", "3",0));
        orderArrayList.add(new ModelOrder(R.drawable.fastfood, "Pommes", "Fritten für die Titten.", "5",0));
        orderArrayList.add(new ModelOrder(R.drawable.water, "Wasser", "Still und sanft, so mag ich es.", "5",0));
        orderArrayList.add(new ModelOrder(R.drawable.burger, "Burger", "Ach mir fällt nichts ein.", "10",0));

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager recLiLayoutManager = layoutManager;

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recLiLayoutManager);

        adapter = new OrderAdapter(this, orderArrayList);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        epicDialog = new Dialog(this);

        btnCheckout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showWaitingPopUp();


            }
        });


    context = this;
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (nfcAdapter == null) {
            // Stop here, we definitely need NFC
            Toast.makeText(this, "This device doesn't support NFC.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
        readFromIntent(getIntent());

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
        tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected };




    }

    // Read from NFC Tag
    private void readFromIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                }
            }
            buildTagViews(msgs);
        }
    }
    private void buildTagViews(NdefMessage[] msgs) {
        if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) return;

        String text = "";
//        String tagId = new String(msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getType());
        byte[] payload = msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
        String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16"; // Get the Text Encoding
        int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 0063; // Get the Language Code, e.g. "en"
        // String languageCode = new String(payload, 1, languageCodeLength, "US-ASCII");

        try {
            // Get the Text
            text = new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, textEncoding);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding", e.toString());
        }

        System.out.println("NFC Content: " + text);
    }

    // Pop Up
    private void showWaitingPopUp() {
        if(adapter.getTotalPrice() != 0) {
        epicDialog.setContentView(R.layout.order_popup_waiting);
        epicDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        btnAbort = (Button) epicDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnAbort);
        // ONLY HERE NFC SHOULD BE CHECKING
        btnAbort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Set all orders count to 0
                for (ModelOrder modelOrder: orderArrayList) {
                    modelOrder.setCounter(0);
                }
                // Notify RecyclerView about the changes
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                NumberFormat n = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
                textView_order_price.setText( n.format(0));
                textView_order_count.setText(0 + "");

                epicDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        epicDialog.show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Keine Auswahl = Kein Essen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        readFromIntent(intent);
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            myTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onTotalChanged(String result) {
        NumberFormat n = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
        textView_order_price.setText( n.format(Integer.parseInt(result)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCountChanged(String result) {
        textView_order_count.setText(result);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        WriteModeOff();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        WriteModeOn();
    }


    private void WriteModeOn(){
        writeMode = true;
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, writeTagFilters, null);
    }

    private void WriteModeOff(){
        writeMode = false;
        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to what you have done with the `writeMode` Boolean Flag.

Have another Boolean called say `nfcEnabled` as a member of the `OrderActivity` class with the default value of `false`

In your `showWaitingPopUp()` set that Flag to `true`

Then in `onNewIntent` skip the tag reading if the flag `nfcEnabled` is not `true`
e.g.
`if (!nfcEnabled) return;`

Then when you have successfully read the correct data from the Tag set the `nfcEnabled` to `false`, this allows you to leave the flag at `true` if the NDEF message was read but it did not have the right contents, so another Tage can be presented.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I implemanted your idea, but the problem is that when I'm holding the NFC Tag on the back of my phone and I'm not in the pop up it will not read but give a sound and jump to a different view.

Comment: The sound is because you are using an older method of reading nfc cards that I would not recommend to use unless you really have to, to support very old Android OS's especially if writing to a card. With `enableForgroundDispatch` another App is actually handling the card reading and producing the sounds then passing your app the data. This also has a side effect that your app is actually paused then resumed while it does the reading which might cause the view to change. Much better to use `enableReaderMode`, you get control of the sound and you app does not get paused.

Comment: Thank you very much @Andrew! I didn't find a good structure tutorial of the NFC. Do you have a good new tutorial, or could you help me with that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've never found a good tutorial for `enableReaderMode`, https://github.com/googlearchive/android-CardReader/tree/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/cardreader is a good if over complicated example. Just enable and disable in onResume and onPause then implement the callback method. Note the callback method is run in a new thread for you when a card is detected then just use the `get` method in the nfc tech classes e.g. `Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);` then just check that `ndef != null` for a full answer ask another question about it.